# In magento 1.7.2, Is it possible to exclude calculation of tax on shipping in only 1 state?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am able to tell magento 1.7.2 apply a set of tax rates for a bunch of zip codes. I can make a tax class and say "Hey tax class use these rates"
but I cant say "Hey Magento can you not charge tax on shipping for state X"

I have about 20000 zip codes for 8 states and MA does not charge tax on shipping, any help would be appreciated.

**Solution after comment**

Create two tax rules one with shipping and one without shipping. The state that will have special rules should have its own tax rule. On check out Magento will look up the zip code from the tax rules.

Answer (score 0):

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/29889/shipping-tax-only-for-certain-states

Literally answers exactly what you need, please read all the comments too.

Comment: You pointed me to the right post, and it was very useful. Thank you.

Comment: Anytime, it's a bit awkward having Magento tagged SO posts and a Magento sub-SO.